# I update my Apps version 4.0 to convert 4.2 and pod not installing

Tags: cocoapods

I update swift_version 4.0 to convert 4.2 app work perfectly but when i install new other pod i have facing this error in terminal  **[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory**. how resolve this issue.

Comment: will you please provide screenshot of terminal and check with `ls` command where you try to `pod install`

Comment: i solve my issue update cocoa-pods its work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Podfile` has to be present in the directory where you type `pod install`. Make sure that you're in the correct directory before installing new pods.